# How to get all spaces of the keys of a json document with regex

Tags: regex

I want to manipulate a JSON-document and to replace all spaces of the keys (but not of the values!) with and underscore.

I have a document like this:

```
{
    "key_1_of_this_json": 3458,
    "key_2_of this beautiful json document ": "text of the second key",
    "key_3": 25870084,
    "key 4 has no underscores but many spaces ": 109520
}
```

And I want to identify all spaces with regex - but for the keys only! The values shouldn't be touched! Because of that the regex should analyze the json document like this:

- "key_1_of_this_json" -> this key is okay -> nothing to do
- "key_2_of this beautiful json document " -> this key isn't okay -> regex should recognize 5 spaces in the key and shouldn't touch the spaces of the value ("text of the second key")
- key_3 -> this key is okay too -> nothing to do
- "key 4 has no underscores but many spaces " -> this key isn't okay -> regex should recognize 8 spaces

Comment: This doesn't really sound like a problem suitable for regex.  You need a first-class, Turing-complete programming language.  Write a simple parser in your language of choice.

Comment: You need a JSON parser to know where the keys are.

Answer (score 1):

Regex does not seem to be the best tool here, better just parse the JSON, process the object and serialise again (if needed).

```js
const json = `{
    "key_1_of_this_json": 3458,
    "key_2_of this beautiful json document ": "text of the second key",
    "key_3": 25870084,
    "key 4 has no underscores but many spaces ": 109520
}`;

const parsed = JSON.parse(json);

const newObject = {}
for (const key of Object.keys(parsed))
  newObject[key.replace(/ /g, '_')] = parsed[key];
const newJson = JSON.stringify(newObject);

console.log(newJson);
```